# SQL developer error with "disable modules and continue"

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to open SQL developer and getting following error on a dialogue box

> Warning - could not install some modules: oracle.java_annotations -
>   org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso:
>   D:\sqldeveloper-4.0.2.15.21-no-jre\sqldeveloper\ide\lib\annotations.jar:
>   Not found bundle:oracle.java_annotations oracle.ide_boot -
>   org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso:
>   D:\sqldeveloper-4.0.2.15.21-no-jre\sqldeveloper\ide\lib\ide-boot.jar:
>   Not found bundle:oracle.ide_boot oracle.ide.macros -
>   org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso:
>   D:\sqldeveloper-4.0.2.15.21-no-jre\sqldeveloper\jdev\extensions\oracle.ide.macros.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.ide.macros oracle.jgoodies_looks -
>   org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso:
>   D:\sqldeveloper-4.0.2.15.21-no-jre\sqldeveloper\jlib\jgoodies-looks.jar:
>   Not found bundle:oracle.jgoodies_looks oracle.external.xdk -
>   org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso:
>   D:\sqldeveloper-4.0.2.15.21-no-jre\sqldeveloper\external\oracle.external.xdk.jar:
>   Not found bundle:oracle.external.xdk oracle.external.xmlparser -
>   org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso:
>   D:\sqldeveloper-4.0.2.15.21-no-jre\sqldeveloper\external\oracle.external.xmlparser.jar:
>   Not found bundle:oracle.external.xmlparser oracle.ideimpl.peek -
>   org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso:
>   D:\sqldeveloper-4.0.2.15.21-no-jre\sqldeveloper\ide\extensions\oracle.ideimpl.peek.jar:
>   Not found bundle:oracle.ideimpl.peek oracle.javamodel_rt -
>   org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso:
>   D:\sqldeveloper-4.0.2.15.21-no-jre\sqldeveloper\external\oracle.javamodel-rt.jar:
>   Not found bundle:oracle.javamodel_rt oracle.javatools -
>   org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso:
>   D:\sqldeveloper-4.0.2.15.21-no-jre\sqldeveloper\ide\lib\javatools.jar:
>   Not found bundle:oracle.javatools oracle.external.nlsrtl -
>   org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso:
>   D:\sqldeveloper-4.0.2.15.21-no-jre\sqldeveloper\external\oracle.external.nlsrtl.jar:
>   Not found bundle:oracle.external.nlsrtl oracle.peek -
>   org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso:
>   D:\sqldeveloper-4.0.2.15.21-no-jre\sqldeveloper\ide\lib\peek.jar: Not
>   found bundle:oracle.peek oracle.external.jxlayer -
>   org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso:
>   D:\sqldeveloper-4.0.2.15.21-no-jre\sqldeveloper\external\oracle.external.jxlayer.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.external.jxlayer oracle.external.berkeleydb -
>   org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso:
>   D:\sqldeveloper-4.0.2.15.21-no-jre\sqldeveloper\external\oracle.external.berkeleydb.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.external.berkeleydb oracle.ide.vfs -
>   org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso:
>   D:\sqldeveloper-4.0.2.15.21-no-jre\sqldeveloper\ide\extensions\oracle.ide.vfs.jar:
>   Not found bundle:oracle.ide.vfs oracle.icons -
>   org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso:
>   D:\sqldeveloper-4.0.2.15.21-no-jre\sqldeveloper\external\oracle.icons.jar:
>   Not found bundle:oracle.icons oracle.ide.persistence -
>   org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso:
>   D:\sqldeveloper-4.0.2.15.21-no-jre\sqldeveloper\ide\extensions\oracle.ide.persistence.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.ide.persistence oracle.idert -
>   org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso:
>   D:\sqldeveloper-4.0.2.15.21-no-jre\sqldeveloper\ide\lib\idert.jar: Not
>   found bundle:oracle.idert oracle.javatools_jndi_local -
>   org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso:
>   D:\sqldeveloper-4.0.2.15.21-no-jre\sqldeveloper\external\oracle.javatools-jndi-local.jar:
>   Not found bundle:oracle.javatools_jndi_local
>   org.eclipse.equinox.common - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso:
>   D:\sqldeveloper-4.0.2.15.21-no-jre\sqldeveloper\equinox\org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.6.0.v20100503.jar:
>   Not found bundle:org.eclipse.equinox.common oracle.ide.navigator -
>   org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso:
>   D:\sqldeveloper-4.0.2.15.21-no-jre\sqldeveloper\ide\extensions\oracle.ide.navigator.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.ide.navigator oracle.javatools_jdk -
>   org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso:
>   D:\sqldeveloper-4.0.2.15.21-no-jre\sqldeveloper\jdev\lib\jdkver.jar:
>   Not found bundle:oracle.javatools_jdk oracle.ide.searchbar -
>   org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso:
>   D:\sqldeveloper-4.0.2.15.21-no-jre\sqldeveloper\ide\extensions\oracle.ide.searchbar.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.ide.searchbar oracle.ide_osgi -
>   org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso:
>   D:\sqldeveloper-4.0.2.15.21-no-jre\sqldeveloper\ide\lib\oracle.ide.osgi.jar:
>   Not found bundle:oracle.ide_osgi oracle.external.odl -
>   org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso:
>   D:\sqldeveloper-4.0.2.15.21-no-jre\sqldeveloper\external\oracle.external.odl.jar:
>   Not found bundle:oracle.external.odl oracle.external.xdb -
>   org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso:
>   D:\sqldeveloper-4.0.2.15.21-no-jre\sqldeveloper\external\oracle.external.xdb.jar:
>   Not found bundle:oracle.external.xdb oracle.external.miglayout -
>   org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso:
>   D:\sqldeveloper-4.0.2.15.21-no-jre\sqldeveloper\external\oracle.external.miglayout.jar:
>   Not found bundle:oracle.external.miglayout oracle.ide -
>   org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso:
>   D:\sqldeveloper-4.0.2.15.21-no-jre\sqldeveloper\ide\extensions\oracle.ide.jar:
>   Not found bundle:oracle.ide oracle.uic -
>   org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso:
>   D:\sqldeveloper-4.0.2.15.21-no-jre\sqldeveloper\ide\lib\uic.jar: Not
>   found bundle:oracle.uic oracle.external.oracle_jrf_adminserver -
>   org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso:
>   D:\sqldeveloper-4.0.2.15.21-no-jre\sqldeveloper\external\oracle.external.oracle-jrf-adminserver.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.external.oracle_jrf_adminserver
>   oracle.ide.library - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso:
>   D:\sqldeveloper-4.0.2.15.21-no-jre\sqldeveloper\jdev\extensions\oracle.ide.library.jar:
>   Not found bundle:oracle.ide.library oracle.jewt_core -
>   org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso:
>   D:\sqldeveloper-4.0.2.15.21-no-jre\sqldeveloper\jlib\jewt4.jar: Not
>   found bundle:oracle.jewt_core oracle.external.timing -
>   org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso:
>   D:\sqldeveloper-4.0.2.15.21-no-jre\sqldeveloper\external\oracle.external.timing.jar:
>   Not found bundle:oracle.external.timing oracle.ide.ceditor -
>   org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso:
>   D:\sqldeveloper-4.0.2.15.21-no-jre\sqldeveloper\ide\extensions\oracle.ide.ceditor.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.ide.ceditor oracle.javatools_nodeps -
>   org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso:
>   D:\sqldeveloper-4.0.2.15.21-no-jre\sqldeveloper\external\oracle.javatools-nodeps.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.javatools_nodeps oracle.external.balishare -
>   org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso:
>   D:\sqldeveloper-4.0.2.15.21-no-jre\sqldeveloper\external\oracle.external.balishare.jar:
>   Not found bundle:oracle.external.balishare oracle.external.jdbc -
>   org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso:
>   D:\sqldeveloper-4.0.2.15.21-no-jre\sqldeveloper\external\oracle.external.jdbc.jar:
>   Not found bundle:oracle.external.jdbc oracle.javaxide -
>   org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso:
>   D:\sqldeveloper-4.0.2.15.21-no-jre\sqldeveloper\ide\lib\javax-ide.jar:
>   Not found bundle:oracle.javaxide oracle.ide_print_api -
>   org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso:
>   D:\sqldeveloper-4.0.2.15.21-no-jre\sqldeveloper\ide\lib\ide-print-api.jar:
>   Not found bundle:oracle.ide_print_api oracle.ide.indexing -
>   org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso:
>   D:\sqldeveloper-4.0.2.15.21-no-jre\sqldeveloper\ide\extensions\oracle.ide.indexing.jar:
>   Not found bundle:oracle.ide.indexing oracle.external.oracle_jrf_dms -
>   org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso:
>   D:\sqldeveloper-4.0.2.15.21-no-jre\sqldeveloper\external\oracle.external.oracle-jrf-dms.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.external.oracle_jrf_dms oracle.ide.file -
>   org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso:
>   D:\sqldeveloper-4.0.2.15.21-no-jre\sqldeveloper\ide\extensions\oracle.ide.file.jar:
>   Not found bundle:oracle.ide.file

Comment: why `netbeans` will come into the picture ? :s Re-install your setup cleanly.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I just deleted everything from

```
C:\Users\Bopsi\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\system4.0.2.15.21
```

and it worked.

Comment: Be careful, with this solution you'll lose program settings (saved connections etc.)

Comment: I was just searching for this directory and thought of googling. and boom thank you Bopsi

Comment: Use the solution in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61330713/822870 , to not lose settings.

Answer (score 57):

I came across this problem when I was switching my Java version back and forth from J8 to J11. Resolutions with deleting whole `systemX.X.X.X.X` or `.sqldeveloper` aren't good, because you'll loose all your settings (saved connections etc.).

What worked for me was just deleting `system_cache` folder. I had version 21.2.1.204.1703, so for Linux it was:

```
rm -r ~/.sqldeveloper/system21.2.1.204.1703/system_cache/
```

For Windows it would be:

```
%APPDATA%\SQL Developer\system21.2.1.204.1703\system_cache
```

And this typically expands to something like:

```
C:\Users\<your_name>\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\system21.2.1.204.1703\system_cache
```

Comment: for me also this worked. I am using SQL dev 20.2 on windows 10 and jdk 11

Comment: thanks! worked for me on ubuntu, and my passwords are still there

Comment: Been banging my head again the wall with this one.

Comment: Worked for me, too. Thank you. SQL Developer 22.2 on Windows. Path was: C:\Users\thorsten\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\system22.2.0.173.2018\system_cache.

Comment: this works for ubuntu 22.04 with latest and path to cache as ~/.sqldeveloper/system22.2.1.234.1810

Comment: works for me too with SQL Developer 23.1 on Windows.

Comment: It worked for me SQL Dev version 23.1.0.097.1607

Answer (score 5):

In Ubuntu,
just delete .sqldeveloper from user home directory

Eg:

```
rm -rf /home/username/.sqldeveloper
```

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem and the solution was:

From `SQL_DEVELOPER_HOME`\sqldeveloper\bin 
Edit the file `sqldeveloper.conf`
Update the SetJavaHome pointing to the Java JDK `JAVA_HOME` (Your JDK)

Done

Comment: It worked for me; I have to update Java and set the `SetJavaHome` variable value as this: `C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_281` - in my case, Java is not correctly installed for some unknown reason (*i.e. the enviroment variable "Path" is too long and it doesn't have the `;%JAVA_HOME%\bin` attached at the end of its value*), but, the problem described in the OP's question was the same as mine and I was able to solve thanks to your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Similar problem here and none of the solutions shown here helped me.

A workaround<sup>1</sup> I use is:

- Open `SQL Developer` and when the warning appears, right-click on `SQL Developer` icon (*shown in the task bar*) and click for open it. This action will open a second `SQL Developer`, but, without warnings and you can continue as usual.

---

<sup>1</sup> In the current answers and others I found online, they advice against deleting files, so, this workaround is an alternative to changing settings and/or deleting temporal or even physical configuration files.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I have resolved setting the java_home path of the jdk from the comand line. For doing so, open the comand line, put yourself in the "bin" directory of sqldeveloper, typically in "..\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\bin" and type `set java_home=..` where you have to replace the ".." with the path of the jdk directory in your drive.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking in these cases SQL developer seems to have trouble to find the Java installation on you machine. To remedy this you can delete the settings (SQL-developer will ask for the path to your java installation) or you correct the path manually).

---

SQL Developer 19.4 saves settings in two different folders in my roaming folder

(i.e. %userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\, or C:\Users[your user name]\AppData\Roaming)

1. %userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\system[version number] (see Bopsis answer) -> deleting this folder did not help in my case

and a single file 'product.conf'

2. %userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\sqldeveloper[version number]\product.conf

-> I deleted this file and sql developer asked at next startup for the location of the JDK on my system)

(or if you prefere: In that file 'product.conf' change the setting SetJavaHome to point to you Java JDK, eg.

`SetJavaHome C:\dev\repository\jdk\jdk1.8.0_241`

In my configuration the file "sqldeveloper.conf" in the '...\bin\' folder (see Cralfaros answer) did not have a "SetJavaHome"-setting but you might want to check there too if problems persist.

I had this problem with sql developer 19.4 *without* JRE included. Reinstall probably will only solve problems in cases when JRE *is* included in the install.

Otherwise the fresh install will only use the old settings. deleting the old settings will on the other hand solve the problem without reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

For those on windows and not able to find AppData for user

- Press the Windows logo Key + R to launch the Run dialog box. Once the
  box opens, type %APPDATA% and press “Enter”
- go to Roaming/SQL Developer/systemx.x.x.x.x/
- delete "system_cache" folder
- Restart sqldeveloper.exe

Answer (score 0):

In my Amazon WorkSpace this happens a lot. It has always helped to delete "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer" and re-import my connections.