# SQL Developer Crashes when booting up in Oracle DB Developer VM

Tags: sql, database, oracle, virtual-machine, oracle-sqldeveloper

I was able to successfully configure and run the development VM which had all the features needed for learning SQL. But I am not able to open the SQL developer on the VM.

The warning it gives me is this.

[[image: Warning from SQL Developer][1]]

Comment: maybe try uninstalling and download a fresh copy.

Comment: Weird..just download 20.4 on your main machine and use it to connect to the db on the vm

Comment: Please, [**do not post images of errors**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question#285557).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL developer error with "disable modules and continue"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31809319/sql-developer-error-with-disable-modules-and-continue)